# How can I show that $\lim_{\rho \to 0}\int_{\partial B_{\rho}} u_x dy - u_ydx = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $B_\rho = \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \leq \rho\}$ and $u$ is $C^1$, how can I show that:
$$\lim_{\rho \to 0}\int_{\partial B_{\rho}} u_x dy - u_ydx = 0$$

I know that by Green's theorem:

$$\int_{\partial B_{\rho}} u_x dy - u_ydx = \iint_{B_\rho} u_{xx} + u_{yy} dx dy$$

but I'm not sure what to do next...

Comment: Should it be $B_\rho = \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \leq \rho\}$?

Comment: Yes, it should, I fixed that.

Comment: You can't apply Green's theorem like that, because you only know that $u$ is $C^1$.

Comment: Is it still possible to show that the limit is 0 then? If not, there might be a mistake in the question, because I am being asked to prove that the limit is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler than you are expecting. Since $u$ is $C^1$ it and its derivatives are bounded. Parameterize $\partial B_\rho$ by $x(t) = \rho \cos t$ and $y(t) = \rho \sin t$. Then
$$\int_{\partial B_\rho} u_x \, dy = \int_0^{2\pi} u_x(\rho \cos t,\rho \sin t) \rho \cos t \, dt$$
so that $$\left| \int_{\partial B_\rho} u_x \, dy \right| \le 2\pi M \rho$$ where $M = \sup |u_x|$. The other integral satisfies a similar estimate.